# Mockito returns the same result for different parameter values

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I get this weird behaviour with Mockito but I m not sure if it is the expected behaviour in any manner :-(. Following code is a fictitious Java code I came up with to highlight the point.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class StringServiceTest {

    enum Style {
        NONE, ITALIC, BOLD
    }

    private class StringService {

        public List<String> getString(Set<String> words, long fontSize, Style fontStyle) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetString() {

        StringService stringService = Mockito.mock(StringService.class);

        Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>();

        when(stringService.getString(words, 12L, Style.BOLD)).thenReturn(sentence);

        List<String> result = stringService.getString(words, 234L, Style.ITALIC);
        List<String> result1 = stringService.getString(words, 565L, Style.ITALIC);
        List<String> result2 = stringService.getString(words, 4545L, Style.NONE);

        assertThat("Sentences are different", result.hashCode() == result1.hashCode());
        assertThat("Sentences are different", result.hashCode() == result2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Since Mockito cannot read the source code it relies on the static state of the code recording what should be returned on each invocation. But this behaviour totally perplexed me as it returns the same object for different parameters when it should send null or empty object for a set of parameters it has not programmed for. 
I'm using Java 1.7.0_79 and Mockito 1.10.19 with Junit 4.11.
Am I missing something important or can someone kindly explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've only stubbed the following invocation

```
when(stringService.getString(words, 12L, Style.BOLD)).thenReturn(sentence);
```

which doesn't match any of your invocations

```
List<String> result = stringService.getString(words, 234L, Style.ITALIC);
List<String> result1 = stringService.getString(words, 565L, Style.ITALIC);
List<String> result2 = stringService.getString(words, 4545L, Style.NONE);
```

For unstubbed methods, Mockito uses [`RETURN_DEFAULTS`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEFAULTS).

> The default `Answer` of every mock if the mock was not stubbed.
>   Typically it just returns some empty value.
>
> Answer can be used to define the return values of unstubbed
>   invocations.
>
> This implementation first tries the global configuration. If there is
>   no global configuration then it uses `ReturnsEmptyValues` (returns
>   zeros, **empty collections**, nulls, etc.)

In other words, every one of your calls to `getString` is actually returning some empty `List` (Mockito's current implementation returns a new `LinkedList` instance).

Since all these `List` instances are empty, they all have the same `hashCode`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are mocking that class, it is returning a general return value. It's not returning what you think it is. In this case it's a `LinkedList`. The list `hashCode` depends on the contents:

```
/**
 * Returns the hash code value for this list.
 *
 * <p>This implementation uses exactly the code that is used to define the
 * list hash function in the documentation for the {@link List#hashCode}
 * method.
 *
 * @return the hash code value for this list
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

If you print out the hashCode, you will find that it is `1`.

Comment: You made a good point that new ArrayList<String>().hashCode() returns 1. +1 for that. Your point together with Sotirios answer explains exactly what I was after.Thanks you.